# Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type text/html - apache2

Tags: php, html, css, apache2

I have a problem with my CSS files not running on my website.
The error messages is below:

[image: error messages]

And here is the PHP file that I believe has the problem.

[image: PHP]

I have tried changing `text/html` to `text/css` with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

Many reasons can cause this problem:

- Check if you have any .htaccess that redirect all URLs to the same page.
- if files are in external server, maybe the server return a 404 not found response page.

Try to open a css file and see the content maybe it will help you to solve the problem.